# Using the chain rule to relate inverse function's derivative to function's derivatives

Tags: calculus, inverse

We know the **inverse functon identity:**

$$ f(g(x) ) = x$$

then,

$$ \frac{df(g)}{dg} \frac{dg(x)}{dx} = 1$$

However, if we have

$$ q(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx}$$

Is,

$$ q(g)  = \frac{df(g) }{dx} = \frac{df(g)}{dg} \frac{ dg}{dx} \tag{1}$$

What's wrong with the above equation?

---

Consider a counter example for (1):

$$ f = 2x \tag{2}$$

And,

$$ g = \frac{x}{2} \tag{3}$$

Combining (2) and (3),

$$ f= 4 \frac{x}{2} = 4g$$

Notice that

$$ \frac{df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx} = 2 \neq 1$$

What went wrong?

Tl;dr Is plugging inverse then derivative equal to  derivative then plugging in inverse? Why/  why not?

Comment: Why in the world is $(df/dg)(dg/dx) = 1$?  That's just $df/dx$, which is exactly what it was before you started making changes of variable.

Comment: Because $ f(g) = x$ , then $ \frac{df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx} = 1$, the input of the derivative has changed under substitution @KCd

Comment: Try an *actual example*: $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$, so $f = g^4$. Compute $df/dg$ and then $dg/dx$ and write the product as a function of $x$. It is not $1$.  Or even more simply, take $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = x/2$, so $f = 4g$ and write the product as a function of $x$. It is not $1$. Sit down and do the calculation, don't just insist it is $1$.

Comment: The actual identity is $\frac{df}{dg} (g(x)) \frac{dg}{dx} (x) = 1$, which does *not* imply $\frac{df}{dg} (x) \frac{dg}{dx} (x) = 1$, this is your mistake

Comment: $$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{ df(g)}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx}$$.. no?

Comment: Please *do an example* on your own (try either one I mentioned).

Comment: $$ f= 4g$$
$$ \frac{df}{dg} = 4$$

And, $ g = \frac{x}{2}$  , $ \frac{dg}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}$... hence $$ \frac{df}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx} = 2$$

Good point.

Comment: i guess this post is an inspiration form [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955762/find-the-area-under-curve-using-the-given-data/3955767#3955767) post posted today ;)

Comment: Indeed it was Albus, Indeed it was.

Comment: @Buraian $\frac{d(f(g)}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}$ need not be equal to $\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dg}{dx}$ so your last counterexample i dont undersatand

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong in the proof I wrote.. there's some thing I'm missing/wrong.

Comment: @Buraian OK so are you asking how the answer came out to be 2 when you thought it should be 1

Comment: yeah basically that, if I were to be more specific then it'd be a contrast in the result I derived vs the final result I got

Comment: by derived i Mean $ \frac{df(g)}{dg} \frac{dg}{dx}$

Comment: @Buraian i have added an answer is it clear now

Answer (score 1):

Well your counter example doesn't make sense .There is a diffrence between $\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}$ and $\frac{df(g)}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}$  In case of your example $$f(x)=2x,g(x)=x/2$$ $$\Rightarrow f(g)=2(x/2)=x$$ $$\frac{df(g)}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}=1$$ as you obtained initially.

I mean to say $$\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}=2$$ is not a counterexample to yourclaim as they are simply different

Comment: If I were to be more precise, what exactly would you label as the difference between the two expressions?

Comment: @Buraian do you agree that $$\frac{d f(g)}{dg}$$ and $$\frac{df}{dg}$$are diffrent

Comment: @Buraian as $f(g)$ nedd not be equal to $f(x)$ their derivatives naturally need not be equal

Comment: I mean, the thing is that you can't differentiate f with g unless f can be written as a functio nof g i.e: $ \frac{df}{dg} \implies \frac{df(g)}{dg}$ maybe I'm missing something basic. Not sure.

Comment: @Buraian actually $$\frac{d(f(g)}{dg}=\frac{df}{dx}$$

Comment: @Buraian So in $\frac{df(g)}{dg}$, we are putting $g$ as a variable, or putting $g$ to where it was $x$. Hence $f(g)=2g$; it's basically the same as taking $\frac{df}{dx}$. But in $\frac{df}{dg}$, we write $f(x)$ in the form of $g(x)$, so we can say $f(x)=4g$.

Comment: @Buraian why cant we diffrentiate say i want derivative of of $f=x^2$ w.r.t $g=2x$  then $\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{d(x^2)}{d(2x)}=x$

Comment: Oh god, I got it now @YuqiaoHuang I got confused between composition and expressing x interms of another quantity

Comment: But still, is composing then derivative equivalent to derivative then compose or not? I'm looking for an explanation in 'words' as to why not

Comment: I mean yeah that part seems alright @AlbusDumbledore

Comment: @Buraian  'is composing then derivative equivalent to derivative then compose or not? I'm looking for an explanation in 'words' as to why not ' could you explain a bit more say by giving an example what you mean

Comment: In words meaning, an explanation in english rather than appealing to symbolic notation

Comment: I think I"ve figured out the root of my problem , made another post about it [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956252/composing-inverse-with-a-function-vs-manipulating-to-have-inverse-in-functions)