# Composing inverse with a function vs manipulating to have inverse in function's expression

Tags: functions

Consider a function $f(x)=2x$ with inverse $g(x)= \frac{x}{2}$, now notice that:

$$ f(x) = 2x = 4 \frac{x}{2} = 4g$$

Or,

$$ f(x) = 4g$$

Now it looks very tempting to say:

$$ f(g) =4g \tag{1}$$

The reason being that it's clear that $f$ is directly dependent on $g$, but.. this quantity is much different from composing $f$ with $g$ i.e:

$$ f(g) = x$$

I'm looking for an argument 'in words' as to why replacing the function dependencies as shown in (1) is not allowed.

Here is the source of confusion, consider the pic below

[image]

Usually composting is said as we have an input which we feed into a function, this function outputs and we feed that output into another function which gives the final output.

Now the structure of the above operations looks very similar to how the expression:

$$ f(x) = 4g$$

Behaves in the sense that you feed in an $x$, that goes into the $g$, you calculate the corresponding output by multiplying by that with definition of $f$

Comment: i dont know how its tempting $$f(x)=4g(x)$$ $$f(g(x)))=4g(g(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The first case you provided a relation between the two functions you've defined:

[image]

However, if we are to saying 'composing functions' then that means to feed the input to a function, that function works on it and feeds it to another one.

[image]

Tl;dr equivalence between rules doesn't imply equivalence of composition of the rules.