# Let $f(x)$ be an invertible function and $x\in [1,5]$. Let g be the inverse of f such that $g(3)=1$ and $g(6)=5$, then find..

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f(x)$ be an invertible function and $x\in [1,5]$. Let g be the inverse of f such that $g(3)=1$ and $g(6)=5$, then find $\int_1^5 f(x).dx +\int_5^6 g(x).dx$

The only thing I managed to find out was $f(1)=3$ and $f(5)=6$

I don’t see how it’s possible to integrate without even know what the function is. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the second integral starts at $5$ and not at $3$?

Comment: As @trancelocation mentioned if that is the case [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955762/find-the-area-under-curve-using-the-given-data/3955767#3955767) answer of mine may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the second integral starts at $3$ one can use the following [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) (A very nice proof of this rule without words is given on that page):

$$\int_{{\color{green}{1}}}^{\color{blue}{5}} f(x)\,dx +\int_{{\color{green}{3}}}^{\color{blue}{6}} g(x)\,dx =\color{blue}{5\cdot 6} - \color{green}{1\cdot 3}=27$$

Comment: It did start from 5, but the answer is 27 so it could be wrong

Comment: Then it is most probably a typo if $27$ is the solution.